# How To Join two table username and msg table

Tags: php

How To Join two table username and msg table

table one: users.

```
                        |user_id |  username|
                        |-------------------|  
                        |1       |     joe  |
                        |2       |     james|    
                        |3       |     john |
                        --------------------
```

table two::- msg

```
                        ---------------------
                        |user_id|  msg      |
                        |------ |  -------- |
                        |2      |   hey     |
                        |3      |   hi      |
                        |1      |  sups guys| 
                        |2      |   am good |
                        ---------------------
```

i want result like this:

```
                        --------------------
                        |username| msg      |
                        --------|-----------|
                        |james   |hey       |
                        |john    | hi       |  
                        |joe     | sups guys|
                        |james   | am good  |
```

finally how can i echo it out from database using php on a web browser
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that something like just this :

```
SELECT u.username, m.msg
FROM users u
INNER JOIN msg m ON m.user_id = u.user_id
```

should be ok

Answer (score 0):

You need to use PDO or mysqli extensions for database actions.

Your query should be

```
SELECT username, msg FROM msg JOIN users ON msg.user_id = users.user_id
```

---

Example using PDO:

```
$host = '127.0.0.1';
$db   = 'test';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$charset = 'utf8';

$dsn = "mysql:host={$host};dbname={$db};charset={$charset}";
$opt = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
];
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);

$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT username, msg FROM msg JOIN users ON msg.user_id = users.user_id');
$stmt->execute();
$usersMessages = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: how can i echo it out using php mysql from database to web page